# Create a Contact related to a Person Account

Tags: contact, person-accounts

I'm currently unable to link a Contact with a Person Account as the lookup filter of the "Account Name" displays only the Business Accounts!?!
And if I leave the Account Name field empty, the Contact becomes "Private" and I'm unable to link it via the "Related Accounts" list...
Seems silly in fact so thanks already for your answers.
Regards
Jean-Luc

Comment: Have you enabled Person account in your org? If it is done, contact and account gets merged by default. Does it have the record type enabled?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Any `Account` that is a Person Account exists as a row in both `Account` and `Contact`. The only `Contact` that is allowed to have a Person Account as its `AccountId` is the one that represents the same record.

However if you have Contacts to Multiple Accounts enabled in your org, I believe you can add an Account Contact Relationship between a Person Account and some other contact.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Finally I decided to have a two record types for the person account one for a “person” and one for a “household” and with the Contacts to Multiple Accounts enabled I am able to manage the relationships between a person and a household.
What I am looking now is to have reciprocal relationships in the Contact to Multiple Accounts to define the relationships between persons like parent/child or husband/wife. 
In fact what the NPSP package of Salesforce.org implement ideally. 
If you have some expertise or ideas about reciprocal relationships you are welcome.

Comment: To be sure, making households into another record type of Person Accounts is not ideal. These should be non Person Accounts. I have no further suggestions though because I've never seen a non messy Salesforce implementation of complex interpersonal relationships.

Comment: If you see the NPSP package of Salesforce.org you’ll it’s straightforward.

Comment: What is NPSP package?